# How to use HashMap for this scenario?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-sqlite, android-database

Given the client requirement task to do.

> • Create Vehicle class which includes vehicle Id(Integer) as vehicle
>   number and lot(Integer) as parking lot number. Implement getId() and
>   getLot() that returns vehicle Id and Lot.

Create ParkingLot class that includes parkedVehicle, vehicle_lot_data and which implements the following

```
HashMap<Integer, Vehicle> parkedVehicle = new HashMap<>(); 
HashMap<Integer, Integer> vehicle_lot_data = new HashMap<>();
```

> • parkVehicle(Vehicle, lot) parks vehicle at the lot, check for valid
>   parking, also check that same vehicle is not allowed to park at
>   multiple lots. Return “Lot already taken” if lot already booked by
>   someone and “Vehicle already present” if we are trying to book
>   multiple lots for the same vehicle. • isLotBooked(int lot) return
>   boolean - It checks for the lot which is already booked. Return False
>   for an empty lot and True for the booked lot. •   isVehicleExists(int
>   vehicleId) return boolean - It checks for already existing vehicle.
>   Return True if the vehicle exists else False for the non-existing
>   vehicle.

STEP 3: (Database.java)

Create a class Database to store parking lot data.

> Create a local SQLite database (parking_database.db) •    Create
>   DATABASE_NAME variable and store parking_database.db. •   Implement
>   onCreate, onUpgrade for database creation and database drop.
>   • ParkVehicle(Vehicle) - save parked vehicle to database.
>   • getParkedVehicle(), getParkedVehicle(int vehicleId) - get all parked
>   vehicles return ( Cursor ) •  getAllBookedLots() - get all booked
>   parking lots return ( Cursor )

Design table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE parking_lots (id integer PRIMARY KEY, 
lot_number INTEGER, 
vehicle_number INTEGER UNIQUE);
```

> • Implement ParkVehicleNow() that will get user input data from view,
>   and store the data in these variables vehicle_id_field_txt and
>   vehicle_lot_number_field_txt that will call park(int
>   vehicle_id_field_txt, int vehicle_lot_number_field_txt) function
>   internally. • park(int vehicle_id_field_txt, int
>   vehicle_lot_number_field_txt) - will make use of ParkingLot class and
>   park the vehicle using ParkingLot instance pl and save that vehicle to
>   database using Databaseclass instance db. •   If you are unable to park
>   then make a Toast “Vehicle Already Parked choose a different lot or
>   vehicle” else “Vehicle Parked” message will be Toasted. • Also, don’t
>   forget to perform validation for “Lot already taken” and “Vehicle
>   already present” then don’t park vehicle.

But I am not getting Step 2 how to implement the hashmap in ParkingLot.

What I tired is, here based on the scenario, I am not able to use the hashmap anywhere.

```
public class ParkingLot {
    HashMap<Integer, Vehicle> parkedVehicle = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> vehicle_lot_data = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean isLotBooked(int lot, Context context) {
        Database db = new Database(context);
        return db.isAlreadyLotsExists(String.valueOf(lot));
    }

    public boolean isVehicleExists(int vehicleId, Context context) {
        Database db = new Database(context);
        return db.isAlreadyVehicleExists(String.valueOf(vehicleId));
    }

}


  public Vehicle(){

    }

    public Vehicle(int primaryId,int id, int lot){
        this.id = id;
        this.lot = lot;
        this.primaryId = primaryId;
    }
    public Vehicle(int id, int lot){
        this.id = id;
        this.lot = lot;
    }
    public int id;

    public int getPrimaryId() {
        return primaryId;
    }

    public void setPrimaryId(int primaryId) {
        this.primaryId = primaryId;
    }

    public int primaryId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLot() {
        return lot;
    }

    public void setLot(int lot) {
        this.lot = lot;
    }

    public int lot;

}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Database db = new Database(this);
        db.ParkVehicle(new Vehicle(1000,1));
        db.ParkVehicle(new Vehicle(2000,2));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Vehicle> contacts = db.getParkedVehicle(); //all parked vehicle
        List<String> bookedSlots = db.getAllBookedLots(); //all booked slots

        for (Vehicle cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: " + cn.getPrimaryId() + " ,Vehicle: " + cn.getId() + " ,Lot: " +
                    cn.getLot();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.e("ContactsAllVehicles: ", log);
        }

        for (String cn : bookedSlots) {
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.e("ContactsSlots: ", cn);
        }

        Vehicle vehicle= db.getParkedVehicle(1);
        Log.e("ContactsLots",""+vehicle.getId());

        //checking if lots already exisitng..
        boolean alreadyExist=db.isAlreadyLotsExists("0");
        Log.e("contactsslotsTest",""+alreadyExist);
    }



public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vehicles";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String LOT_NUMBER = "lot_number";
    private static final String VEHICLE_NUMBER = "vehicle_number";
    private static final String PARKING_LOTS = "parking_lots"; //table name

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + PARKING_LOTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + LOT_NUMBER + " INTEGER,"
                + VEHICLE_NUMBER + " INTEGER UNIQUE" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PARKING_LOTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void ParkVehicle(Vehicle contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LOT_NUMBER, contact.getLot()); // Lot number
        values.put(VEHICLE_NUMBER, contact.getId()); // Vehicle number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(PARKING_LOTS, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    Vehicle getParkedVehicle(int id) { //single vehicle
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(PARKING_LOTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        LOT_NUMBER, VEHICLE_NUMBER}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Vehicle contact = new Vehicle(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    public List<Vehicle> getParkedVehicle() {
        List<Vehicle> contactList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + PARKING_LOTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Vehicle contact = new Vehicle();
                contact.setPrimaryId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setLot(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    public List<String> getAllBookedLots(){
        List<String> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + PARKING_LOTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
                contactList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOT_NUMBER)));
                Log.d("contactslotnumber",contactList.toString());

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }}
        return contactList;
    }

    public boolean isAlreadyLotsExists(String name){
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query="SELECT * FROM "+PARKING_LOTS+" WHERE "+LOT_NUMBER+" = "+name;
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

    }

    public boolean isAlreadyVehicleExists(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+PARKING_LOTS+" WHERE "+VEHICLE_NUMBER+" = "+name;
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

        // return contact list



    public int updateContact(Vehicle contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LOT_NUMBER, contact.getLot());
        values.put(VEHICLE_NUMBER, contact.getId());

        // updating row
        return db.update(PARKING_LOTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getPrimaryId())});
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Vehicle contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(PARKING_LOTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getPrimaryId())});
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + PARKING_LOTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

This is what I done but there are some steps which are missing from the requirement. Say for eg: Step 2 I am not sure where to use the hashmap to use the parkVehicle method in ParkingLot class and similarly Step 4 too in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably hashmaps were given in the context of caching the DB data. When you write the vehicle/lot-related data, you use hashmaps as caches (utilizing write-back or write-through strategy, whichever matches your requirements or needs) and when you read the data, you always read them from hashmaps i.e. caches

Recall that write-back implies that you write the new data to cache but not DB (the data is written to DB at some later time) and write-through implies that whenever you write the new data, it is written to both cache and DB